# Help needed with Microsoft Prism application

Tags: c#, prism, mef

I'm creating a new Prism4 application with MEF and it works nice. I've created the Shell, etc and everything is OK.

But now I need to create a new **Window** with a **Region** inside it but it seems like the region is not registered with the **RegionManager** (see the Window_Closing event) and the Region in the window work well because the views injected into it are shown.

Here's the code for the new Window

**Wizard.xaml**

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <Button Content="_Previous" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" /> 
    <Button Content="_Next" /> 
  </StackPanel> 
  <ContentControl cal:RegionManager.RegionName="WizardStepsRegion" /> 
</DockPanel>
```

When I try to get the window's Region I get the following exception "KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code", "The region manager does not contain the WizardStepsRegion region."

**Wizard.xaml.cs**

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{ 
  object asdf = regionManager.Regions["WizardStepsRegion"]; 
}
```

Why the region is not registered in the region manager?

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you creating the shell using    
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()    {        return Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();    } ??

Comment: In my previous project, we used Prism v2 and it was a nightmare getting this to work. I hope the v4 answer is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a dialog. Are you Importing that dialog or creating it with `new Wizard()`? If you are creating it with the `new` operator, the RegionManager won't know anything about it. You can manually tell the RegionManager about the window using [SetRegionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.presentation.regions.regionmanager.setregionmanager.aspx).

```
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(window, myRegionManager);
```

Then the RegionManager will know all about your type, discover its regions, etc. The other option is to Import the Wizard type and just `.Show()` it when you want, but sometimes this isn't practical.

Comment: Yes, I'm creating a new dialog. Here's how I create it

    Wizard wizard = (Wizard)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(typeof(Wizard));
    wizard.ShowDialog();

If this why is unpractical how can I do it better?

Thank you.

Comment: One more thing. I'm using Prism v4 and RegionManager has no such method. How can I do it in Prism v4?. Thank you

Comment: @Robe: that's not necessarily wrong or impractical. You just have a choice. You can either do the `new`, then call `SetRegionManager`, or you can create a property of `[Import]public Wizard Wizard { get; set; }` and do `this.Wizard.ShowDialog();` It's up to you.